# How to find the location of an older installed java on linux?

Tags: java, version

Please be patient with me if you find the question is basic for you as a professional.

For running a program, java version of 1.7 is required. however the current java version on our cluster is 1.8 (see below). I think the java of 1.7 has been installed, but I don't know its location. Could you please let me know how to find the location of java 1.7? I want to add it to PATH for running my program

```
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

Thanks

Comment: See if it is in `C:\Program Files\Java`

Comment: @3kings there is no C:\ on Linux

Comment: @Idos Yup... did not read the title lol sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (on most Linux distributions):

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

To view all the packages. Then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to quit the `update`...

Edit: Just found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/569633/what-is-command-to-see-all-java-versions-installed-on-linux) on Superuser.

Edit: 
 Use this command: `for f in $(locate -ber '^java$'); do test -x && echo "$f"; done`

And then copy the appropriate result to your PATH i.e:

> /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've already done it without sudo sine I have no permission, which the output was like below:  'election    Command
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.5.0-gcj/bin/java
   2           /usr/java/latest/bin/java
' . There is no java 1.7, but I'm almost sure it was installed a few month ago by our admin

Comment: Also, if he installed it **without using** an an official package manager, it will not show with this command. Then you might wanna check using: `for f in $(locate -ber '^java$'); do test -x && echo "$f"; done`

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Among the output of your command, there are: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/java and /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre/bin/java, which might be related to java 1.7, am I right? sorry, please kindly tell me which one should be add to PATH?

Comment: @Mary no problem. You should add this: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin   read more here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/

Comment: Surly. But, as it's the comment, I could just up vote it that it dosen't work. please create an answer instead of the comment, your comment was the great answer for my question